# username input and matching using python-(Stuck in while loop)

Tags: python, database, class, while-loop

I want to create a class based **user registration portal** and for that I wanted to add some usernames. But if they are already taken, then the code should prompt the
user to add another username and I tried to do so with this code.

```
a=0
User=['name123']
username=raw_input("Enter username : ")
while a==0:
   for i in User:
      if i==username:
         a=0
         break
      else:
         a=1
   if a==0:
      usernarme=raw_input("Username already taken.\nEnter another username :")
```

But it gets stuck in the loop and displays the following message repeatedly
even after entering a valid username. What I am doing wrong?

> "Username already taken"

Comment: variable name typo at last line probably. Btw, why did you added `class` tag if there is no `class` in provided snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will fix all your issues with loop.

```
User=['name123']
username=raw_input("Enter username : ")
while username in User:
    username=raw_input("Username already taken.\nEnter another username :")
```

P.S. I'm strongly recommend you to read [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) and [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more pythonic version of your code, that's easier to understand and to fix:

```
users = ['name123']
username = raw_input("Enter username : ")
while username in users:
  username = raw_input("Username already taken.\nEnter another username :")
```

Notes:

- Always use lower case for variable names.
- Use `in` instead of looping over users explicitly in the loop.
- Avoid `break` in a while loop and rather change the value of
  your loop condition.

Comment: it appears like we wrote our answers at the same time. I didn't steal your code if that's what you think happened.

Comment: Doesnt matter, because i was to lazy, to write why my code is better than provided one.